# Bottom navigation bar doesn't work properly on android studio (java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

My bottom navigation bar looks visually okay it contains 4 icons each moving you to a different activity and the default one is the "home" activity.

I made my navigation bar with a menu btw.

Whenever you click on an icon in order to move to another activity it moves you into that activity but the bottom navigation bar (who is supposed to highlight the screen you are in) doesn't update unless you press on the same icon again, whenever you click to move another activity it highlights the "home" activity first, only if you click the same icon does it update.

This is my code.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.post:
            Toast.makeText(CreateNewPost.this, "Post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;


        case R.id.myProfile:
            Toast.makeText(CreateNewPost.this, "My Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(CreateNewPost.this, UserProfile.class);
            startActivity(profileIntent);
            break;


        case R.id.explore:
            Toast.makeText(CreateNewPost.this, "Explore", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent newPostIntent = new Intent(CreateNewPost.this, Explore.class);
            startActivity(newPostIntent);
            break;

        case R.id.home:
            Toast.makeText(CreateNewPost.this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(CreateNewPost.this, HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            break;

        default:


    }

    return true;
}
```

[And this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwhst.png)

I want the navigation bar to highlight the correct activity (the one you are on)

Comment: Can you please explain how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: Thought it might be related cause I use a lot of firebase in my project

Comment: So it's a question related to the UI, right?

Comment: have you set the same Ids in the graph and in the menu? also, I suggest you use only one activity and as many fragments as you want. that's what google recommend. 
`please study this and you will thank me later`.
https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-compose/unit-4